# How to predict the imageView height before rendering the actually image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am having a ImageView in a staggered list view and I want to load images from internet. And i need to show a loading symbol till the image gets loaded but the loading image should be of same dimension as the image that is going to load.

I want something similar to Facebook app in android. It will show a loading symbol with predetermined height before image is loaded. I have the original height and width of the image as meta data but i am wondering how to calculate the height of the image based on the device dimension.

Comment: take a list in one xml file and make a new different xmlfile forelement of list  in that xml file just give the decleare image and text what ever you want that sit

Comment: <Imageview width"wrap_content" and height also "wrap_content" size of image will automatically wrapped either any size of image

Comment: i think u didnt get my question properly. The image is loaded from remote server and i should show a loading image till the original image is loaded from server. and that loading image should have same dimensions as the original image

Comment: @amitsharma : no u really didnt get my point

Comment: Hey did you later solve this?? i really would like to know how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1. Ensure that all your images will be the same size, either by changing the size of the content at the source, or adjusting the size after receiving the image.
2. Have a separate request that returns the dimensions of each image. This request will load much faster as there is less data being transferred, and you can then asynchronously load images.